# How to use ::http::formatQuery in tcl with subkeys and values in main key

Tags: tcl

General POST operation like so are working fine for me:

```
::http::geturl $url -query [::http::formatQuery key1 value1 key2 value 2]
```

But I want to execute the POST operation with keys, subkeys, and values:

```
::http::geturl $url -query [::http::formatQuery Key {subkey1 value1 subkey2 value2}]
```

When I try posting from firefox it works fine, but I don't know how to do the same thing with tcl.

What syntax do I use when I want to POST keys and subkeys while using `::http::formatQuery`? Or is there an alternative?

Comment: What output do you expect from formatQuery?

Comment: In general POST operation (example: %::http::geturl -query [::http::formatQuery key1 value1 key2 value 2]) is working fine. But I don't know what should be the ouput format from the ::http::formatQuery, my aim is execute the POST operation when we have keys, subkeys and values(Example:Key {subkey1 value1 subkey2 value2}. I tired these things by using POSTER plugin in firefox browser, it is working fine. Same thing i am trying to automate bu using tcl.

Comment: We're trying to comprehend just what you're trying to do. Do you want to end up with `key1=value1&key2=value2` as a value itself or what?

Comment: yes. In my case i have the payload like below which I am trying to automate.{
        Authentication: {
        username: test,
        password: abcd12$,
    }

Answer (score 1):

We're very clear what your input is. But what **output** do you want? Donal and I have both asked that.

```
% array set params {KeyA {subkey1A value1A subkey2A value2A} KeyB {subkey1B value1B subkey2B value2B}}
% http::formatQuery {*}[array get params]
KeyA=subkey1A%20value1A%20subkey2A%20value2A&KeyB=subkey1B%20value1B%20subkey2B%20value2B
```

If you're interested in providing authentication credentials to the server, you don't do that in the query string: http://wiki.tcl.tk/6087